# Search result is not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an issue in searching records from the PostgreSQL with particular search keyword but no record is displaying here is the code

```
 filter_text=params[:filter_search]
 @outputs = Output.where("name LIKE '%#{filter_text}%'").order("name ASC")
```

Comment: do you have any value in params[:filter_search]

Comment: check for the case of the value you are passing and the value in psql

Comment: are there any records that match that criterion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) gem, it will allow you to use simple methods to `search`. Using `ransack`, you will only need to do this:

```
@outputs = Output.search(name_cont: params[:filter_search]).result.order("name ASC")
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this :

```
    filter_text=params[:filter_search] 
    @outputs = Output.where("name LIKE ?","%#{filter_text}%").order("name ASC")
```

Comment: Or as some would formulate **Please for the love of god, use bind variables** - I hoped SQL injection died 10 years ago...

Answer (score 3):

If you are going for case insensitive search go for `ILIKE`

```
filter_text = params[:filter_search]
@outputs = Output.where("name ILIKE ?", "'%#{filter_text}%'").order("name ASC")
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
filter_text=params[:filter_search]
@outputs = Output.where("name LIKE '%#{filter_text}%'").order("name ASC")
```

Try the following:

```
filter_text=params[:filter_search]
@outputs = Output.where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{filter_text}%"]).order("name ASC")
```

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to search is to use [Ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack). Which provides you an efficient search mechanism.